# C# Method will not strip out duplicates.

Tags: c#, lambda

Need help with this lambda expression. My method is ineffective at eliminating duplicates from a record set.

```
private DataTable StripDuplicatesFromClientLeadTable(DataSet  dsLeadTrack)
{
    var dataTable = dsLeadTrack.Tables[0];
    if (dataTable.Rows.Count == 0) return dataTable;
    var result = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("ClientId"))
        .Select(g => g.First())
        .CopyToDataTable();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Do you have sample input records and what you want the output to be ?

Comment: I have a data table that returns from a stored procedure. I added functionality to my application so that more views could see the data. In doing so i found that my data set included duplicate records into my data set.